# How many concurrent uploads from Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery we can request?

Tags: google-bigquery

On the [doc](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/developers_guide#importingatable), it states that you can upload multiple files from Storage to a table in separate requests:

> Create a CSV file to populate your table - Data used to populate your
>   table is uploaded as a CSV file. Maximum size for a single source file
>   is 4GB, but you can import multiple source files to a table, either in
>   a single request or in separate requests.

Can those requests be issued concurrently? If yes, what will be a maximum concurrent number of uploading requests per account/bucket/table? If there's no explicit quota on those numbers, does it mean you can increase uploading throughput as much as you want by issuing the uploading requests?

Thanks,

Kaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BigQuery quotas are listed here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/quota-policy

In summary, each import request can have a maximum of 500 files (each has to be under 4Gb). You can make two import requests per minute, with a max of 1,000 import requests per day

Comment: Thanks, Michael! BTW, can you tell me what was the maximum uploading thruput you've ever seen on the importing? I just wanted to know a rough number for back-of-the-envelope kind of estimation.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have an SLA for ingestion time, and the import speed versus data size is not currently predictable. However, I have been able to ingest hundreds of Gigabytes of CSV data (that was first gziped then staged in Cloud Storage) in ~ half an hour (when done in batch ingestion job).

Comment: That is so valuable info! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

2013 update:

In summary, each import request can have a maximum of 10,000 files (each has to be under 1Tb, without new lines in the strings).

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/quota-policy#import